# Django messages being displayed twice

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django's message framework, and I have a very odd problem where my messages are being displayed twice in the template, even though {{messages|length}} is 1

My view

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(user=request.user, meta=meta, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        if 'uploaded_image' in request.FILES:
            #TODO limit image size, check mime type
            filename = request.FILES['uploaded_image']
            destination = open('%s/%s' % (settings.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH, form.filename), 'wb+')
            for chunk in filename.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close() 

        print 'adding success message' #this is printed once
        messages.success(request, 'Settings saved.') #this message is displayed twice
        #messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Yup. Saved.')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('someview'))
    else:
        print form.errors
        messages.error(request, 'Error updating settings. See errors below.')
```

in my template:

```
{% block message%}
{{message.count}}
{% if messages %}
{{messages|length}}
    {% for message in messages%}
        <p class="{{message.tags}}">{{message}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `{{message.count}}` to `{{messages.count}}`. Do you get the same output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was a template inheritance issue. Double check and make sure you don't have the same block in two different templates.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me fix a long standing bug, obvious really

Answer (score 2):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32652157/2558618) is for a different question, I was having this issue and it helped me resolve it.

To summarize, the following code can be added to settings.py:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

This changes the messages from being stored in CookiesStorage to SessionStorage, which in some cases are more reliable and prevent double displaying of messages, or not displaying at all.