# Django messages not showing after HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-messages

Tried tonnes of stuff out there but none of them really helped.

I have a `URL` for example:

http://localhost:8000/user/edit-transaction/?object_id=23a959d0561711e59e36acd1b8679265&type=grossary

which calls the below `view`:

```
def edit_transaction(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        if something is True:
            messages.error(request, 'Error message here')

            # this don't work
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

            # but this work
            template = "user/xyz/abc.html"
            render(request, template)
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
    else:
        context = {
             'key1': 'value1', 
             'key2': 'value2',
        }
        template = "user/xyz/abc.html"
        render(request, template, context)
```

And inside template:

```
{% if messages %}

<h1>I am inside MESSAGES</h1>

    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{ message|escape|safe }}</div>
        {% elif message.tags == 'error' %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ message|escape|safe }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

It's getting inside the `if` here `if something is True:` and getting redirected to the same page with the query string as well. But not displaying the error message.

What I want is to redirect to the same page preserving the query string and display the error message. What am I doing wrong here and what changes are recommended (if any).

> Also a doubt, that does Django messages really work after redirection like Flash messages should ??

---

**Edit:**

**1) This don't work:**

```
if something is True:
    messages.error(request, 'Error message here')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

From console:

> [16/Sep/2015 10:57:08]"POST
>   /user/edit-transaction/?object_id=23a959d0561711e59e36acd1b8679265&type=grossary
>   HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [16/Sep/2015 10:57:08]"GET
>   /user/edit-transaction/?object_id=23a959d0561711e59e36acd1b8679265&type=grossary
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 8832

**2) This works:**

```
if something is True:
    messages.error(request, 'Error message here')
    template = "user/xyz/abc.html"
    render(request, template)
```

From console:

> [16/Sep/2015 10:57:08]"POST
>   /user/edit-transaction/?object_id=23a959d0561711e59e36acd1b8679265&type=grossary
>   HTTP/1.1" 302 0

So, basically what I understood from above is that the `messages` is getting expired with an additional request (redirect, 200).

And in templates, it is not getting inside the `{% if messages %}` as well to print `<h1>I am inside MESSAGES</h1>`

Comment: Did you add `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` context processor into `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes I am done with doing all that.

Comment: Can you print `message.tags` as it might be something different then a simple string?

Comment: please explain what the intended behavior of the view is. Is the indentation right? Do you need an else to return the template if false in the POST?

Comment: Also it is better to use `message.level` to check the type of message. Ex: `{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}` checks if message is error type.

Comment: By the way, why don't you try using `request.get_full_path()` over `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` if you want to redirect to same page with same query string? `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` also contains domain information which I suspect redirecting using absolute url messes up something with messages framework.

Comment: @ozgur: Nope, still no luck. :(

Comment: Side note: `Http404` is an exception, not an `HttpResponse`. The corresponding response is `HttpResponseNotFound`.

Comment: @dhke Yes corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @All: Figured it out. Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Added below in `local_settings.py` and its **working**.

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

**What was happening ?**

The messages were actually getting stored in **Cookies** (CookieStorage) which is the default Django behaviour. From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage):

> FallbackStorage is the default storage class. If it isn’t suitable to
>   your needs, you can select another storage class by setting
>   MESSAGE_STORAGE to its full import path, for example:
>
> MESSAGE_STORAGE =
>   'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'

**And what is FallbackStorage ?**

> This class first uses CookieStorage, and falls back to using
>   SessionStorage for the messages that could not fit in a single cookie.
>   It also requires Django’s contrib.sessions application.
>
> This behavior avoids writing to the session whenever possible. It
>   should provide the best performance in the general case.

**And what was happening in my case ?**

`Messages` were getting stored in `CookiesStorage`, but for some weird reason (I don't know what) but the `Messages` in `CookiesStorage` were getting expired or deleted for the 2nd request (i.e. redirection after POST) which should not be happening (because this is not how `flashdata` works). And after I switched the default `MESSAGE_STORAGE` to `SessionStorage`, it started working.

Comment: Oh man! You are a life saver. That was exactly my problem. Thank you very much. +1 from me.

Comment: Hi. This works for me too, but just once. Afterwards, If I want to see the messages I have to refresh the browser. That happens in both Firefox and Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: This happens on Safari for me. On Firefox everything works without adding `'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'`...

Answer (score 1):

In my case modifying the `MESSAGE_STORAGE` value as mentioned by @ParagTyagi was not enough. I was having custom `change_list.html` templates for some admin classes and in those I had to add the following code:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <!--li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li-->
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Notice that I've commented the `<li>` tag, otherwise the messages are duplicated.

In addition, there has to be more than one message in the `messages` object. Otherwise, the messages are not displayed neither. If you have just one message to display (e.g. a confirmation of a success operation), then just add another empty message like:

```
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING, "")
```

After the modifications, remember to restart your web server (e.g. Apache) and clear your browser cache.